# Stripe subscription set billing date as first of each month

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm using Stripe Checkout flow to collect the users' payment details and automatically collect the subscription. I have also implemented webhooks to listen to `checkout.session.completed` so that I can edit the subscription. What I want is as follows:

1. Say, the user registers on January 15th. I'm using metered billing, so the user pays $0.00 on the first invoice.
2. In webhooks, I apply a trial period of 7 days to the subscription like so `stripe.subscriptions.update([id], {trial_end: [seven_days_into_future]})`. So the billing anchor date on the subscription becomes the 22nd of each month.
3. However, I would like to set the billing anchor date as the first day of each month. So I would like the user to receive the first invoice for January 22-31 (prorated), and then get invoices for full calendar months onwards.

How do I achieve that?

I cannot set the `billing_cycle_anchor` to the desired date because it accepts only `now` and `unchanged` values...

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with already created subscriptions, then you'll need to add trial periods to shift the `billing_cycle_anchor`:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#using-a-trial-to-change-the-billing-cycle

If you know exactly how you want to structure your trial and `billing_cycle_anchor` at the time the subscription is being created, then you can future-date the `billing_cycle_anchor` during creation:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#new-subscriptions